# How to Export and Import Schema Oracle From Amazon RDS

Tags: oracle, rds

I bought 2 Oracle Databases from RDS Amazone

How to export schema from one oracle database rds which i bought from RDS Amazone. And importing the schema to the orther oracle database which i also bought from RDS Amazone.

For example:
Oracle Database RDS 1:
Endpoint: xx1.yyyyy1.rds.amazonaws.com
DB instance, identifie info: user1
Master username: password1
Master password: password1
SID: ORCL

Oracle Database RDS 2
Endpoint: xx2.yyyyy2.rds.amazonaws.com
DB instance, identifie info: user2
Master username: password2
Master password: password2
SID: ORCL

I installed SQL PLus & SQL Developer & Local Oracle
But i don't know how to import and export.

Comment: see their Docs on DataPump...if you're schema is small, the Database Copy feature in SQL Developer will also do the job just fine https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: Hi @thatjeffsmith, Thank you for your supporting, it's really critical for me. I will follow the method: "Importing Data with Oracle Data Pump and a Database Link".